# Why is this a "hacky" way to import sys?

Tags: python, python-import

I'm no expert in Python, but I'm managing an AWS-CDK repository which has this import along with the following comment in most subfolder classes.

```
# Hacky way to get our utils - due to the way folder structure is right now
import sys

sys.path.append("..")
[...]
```

The folder structure for this project is this :

```
- [...]
- app.py
- pipeline.py
- requirements.txt
- setup.py
- iam
  |- iam.py
- rds
  |- rds.py
- s3
  | - s3.py
```

The `import sys` can be found in `iam/iam.py`, `rds/rds.py`  and `s3/s3.py`.

Why is it a hacky way to do the import, and how can I make it less hacky?

Comment: I think the issue is using `sys.path.append` to make sure that future imports work, not import `sys` itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a hacky way to import `sys`; the hack is that these modules need to modify `sys.path`, which is pretty much always a bad idea, doubly so when adding a *relative path* to `sys.path` (as opposed to resolving the parent folder's absolute path), to be able to "get our utils".

The way to make this less hacky is to properly package things up into a Python package that doesn't need to touch `sys.path` to make its imports work.

Comment: Could please link a reference on how to make a proper package?

Comment: @Caridorc https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages for how to organize your modules into packages, https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/ for how to make them distribution-compliant.

Comment: Thanks @AKX for the link. I will read up on that and see if I can align with the instructions given there.